# Strong induction on a sequence, proving two functions are equal?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Excuse the poor title, but my understanding is still a little fuzzy. Admins feel free to change it

Here is the question from the book.

> suppose that $f_{0}, f_{1}, f_{2}...$ is a sequence defined as:
>
> $f_{0} = 5, f_{1} = 16$
>
> $f_{k} = 7f_{k-1} - 10f_{k-2}$ for all integers $k \geq 2$
>
> Prove that $f_{n} = 3 * 2^n + 2 * 5^n$ for all integers $n \geq 0$

So, when I see this, here is more or less what is coming to my mind as how these are defined, and the implication is that for any positive integer input, f(x) == g(x)

```
f(x):
    if x == 0: return 5
    if x == 1: return 16
    return 7 * f(x-1) - 10 * f(x-2)

g(x):
    return 3 * 2^x + 2 * 5^x
```

This is mostly just how I am visualizing it.

So for the first two steps, I check the 0 and 1 against the g(x) function to confirm, and those work.

Next step is assuming that g(x) is the same as f(x). I imagine the next step is to do the inductive step of g(x) implies g(x+1), but I am a bit lost on the algebraic process of what comes next. Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: $3$ is the base case? $0,1$ are the base cases. Also, $g(x)$ shouldn't have an $n$ in its definition.

Comment: you're right, updated based on comments

Answer (score 2):

According to the question, you already verified the base cases $0$ and $1$.

Now let $n\geq2$ and suppose the statement has been proved for $n-2$ and $n-1$, then
$$f_n = 7f_{n-1}-10f_{n-2} \text.$$
Hence, from the induction hypotheses,
$$f_n = 7(3\cdot 2^{n-1}+2\cdot 5^{n-1})-10(3\cdot 2^{n-2}+2\cdot 5^{n-2})$$
$$= 42\cdot2^{n-2}+70\cdot 5^{n-2}-30\cdot2^{n-2}-20\cdot5^{n-2}$$
$$= 12\cdot2^{n-2}+50\cdot 5^{n-2}$$
$$= 3\cdot 2^n+2\cdot 5^n \text.$$

Comment: is there a n+1 step needed here?

Comment: @corvid: No. The induction hypothesis here is that the result holds for $n-1$ and $n-2$, and that hypothesis has been used to prove that it holds for $n$. One could just as well have carried out the induction step by assuming that it holds for $n$ and $n-1$ and proving it for $n+1$; it really makes no difference.